# How to call function that use part of template parameter pack in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have following problem:

I want to create variadic template class, that must call lambda, that may take first N parameters of template parameter pack (N may vary from 0 to the size of parameters pack and differs for different lambda).

I think, that recursive template helper function, that will check if lambda is invokable, starting with all parameters, should be the best variant, but how can I pass all but last parameters from parameters pack to it and is it possible at all?

At the moment I see it as something like this:

```
template< typename Callable, typename ...Args >
void Call( Callable& cb, Args... args )
{
   using Function = std::remove_reference_t< Callable >;
   if constexpr( std::is_invocable_v< Function, Args... > )
      cb( args... );
   else if constexpr( sizeof...( args ) == 0 )
      cb();
   else
   {
      // Here I want to create shortened_args, that are all args but last one.
      // Call( cb, shortened_args... );
   }
}
```

UPD: I didn't mention it first, but I need C++17 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `std::index_sequence` as helper:

```
template <typename Callable, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::size_t is_invocable_args(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::is_invocable_v<Callable, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...>;
}

// Helper to know max number of args to take from tuple
template <typename Callable, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::size_t max_invocable_args(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    std::array<bool, sizeof...(Is)> a = {
        is_invocable_args<Callable, Tuple>(std::make_index_sequence<Is>{})...
        };
    auto rit = std::find(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), true);
    if (rit == a.rend()) throw "no valid call";
    return std::distance(a.begin(), rit.base()) - 1;
}

template <std::size_t N, typename Callable, typename Tuple>
constexpr std::size_t max_invocable_args()
{
    return max_invocable_args<Callable, Tuple>(std::make_index_sequence<N + 1{});
}

// Call taking some element from tuple
template< typename Callable, std::size_t... Is, typename Tuple >
void Call_Tuple_impl(Callable cb, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& args )
{
    std::invoke(cb, std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(args))...);
}

template< typename Callable, typename ...Args >
void Call( Callable cb, Args... args )
{
    constexpr std::size_t max_arg_count = max_invocable_args<sizeof...(Args), Callable, std::tuple<Args...>>();

    Call_Tuple_impl(cb, std::make_index_sequence<max_arg_count>{}, std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

[C++20 Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00c1f467bd9d3a49)
[C++17 Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7f3184212f836a5) with rewritten `constexpr` `find`.

Comment: Thanks, that solution looks very elegant, I'll try it

Comment: Sadly I forgot to mention, that I need c++17 solution, my fault. As I understand, I can use index_sequence for my initial recursive design, but is it possible to do max_invocable_args in c++17? Preferably with compile-time check. It is far more elegant.

Comment: [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is only `constexpr` in C++20, write your own version [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7c3088dde361ead).

Comment: Found bug in your code, it won't work when number of arguments of lambda will match number of arguments in parameter pack. It seems for me that there should be  return max_invocable_args<Callable, Tuple>(std::make_index_sequence<N+1>{});

Comment: @CrazySage: indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Break it into two pieces.  First, determine how many arguments.  Then invoke with that many arguments.

```
template<class Tup, std::size_t...Is>
auto slice_tuple(Tup tup, std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  using std::get;
  return std::make_tuple(get<Is>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))...);
}
template<std::size_t N, class Tup>
auto front_of_tuple(Tup tup){
  return slice_tuple(std::forward<Tup>(tup), std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

pack up the args into a tuple, get the front N, then std apply.

To perfect forward/avoid copies, use reference wrappers.